# What are the best materials to learn trigonometry fast?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, book-recommendation

Is there any apostille or summary that teaches all the needs to know for trigonometry. I have already studied this but I need to review and the materials I have are too extensive.

Comment: Likely YouTube. Try to search for what specifically you are having trouble with.

Comment: The basis is the trigonometric CIRCLE.

Comment: Yeah YTB helps a lot but some times I have some distractions and I learn more reading

Comment: for what reason? passing tests or gaining knowledge? if for test then just get as many type of questions they have from past exams and do them.

Comment: Try the old classic Trigonometry by Hobson. Don't try to do ALL the exercises unless you have a year to spare.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A"Sidney+Luxton+Loney" and     https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A"Hobson%2C+Ernest+William%2C+1856-1933"

Comment: Thanks people, yeah for now I need for test, but I was stdying it and its very cool